# MongoNetworkError with Mongoose and AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose, aws-lambda

I've followed the Mongoose best practice article on connecting to mongo with AWS Lambda functions https://mongoosejs.com/docs/lambda.html

And my connection code looks like this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let conn = null;

const uri = process.env.MONGO_URL;

const mongoConnect = async function(context) {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  if (conn == null) {
    conn = mongoose.connect(uri).then(() => mongoose);
    await conn;
  }

  return conn;
};

module.exports = mongoConnect;
```

And it works perfectly fine. However when I have peaks in my client applications and the connections number start to reach the upper limit. I am faced with the following error

```
INFO    MongoNetworkError: 80BCBCD9377F0000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1586:SSL alert number 80

    at connectionFailureError (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:367:20)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:290:22)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  cause: [Error: 80BCBCD9377F0000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1586:SSL alert number 80
  ] {
    library: 'SSL routines',
    reason: 'tlsv1 alert internal error',
    code: 'ERR_SSL_TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR'
  },
  connectionGeneration: 10,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
}
```

The problem that when this happens is that the whole application becomes unusable for couple of minutes and then it returns to working back fine automatically.

I am wondering if there is a way to prevent this from happening either by changing the way I connect to Mongo or by changing the settings for AWS Lambda or for MongoDB Atlas. Or is the only way to go is to upgrade to a higher tier in Mongo Atlas with more connections.